# How to create curved texts like these?

Tags: fonts, text

[image: the wave-like text.]

How do I create these wave-like form in Adobe Illustrator/photoshop? I tried to use blended objects and applied the text on it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it is by using Adobe Illustrator's Envelope Distort.

See the step by step in the images below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 This is how I'd do it.. but no need to create outlines. Live Type will work. Also.. after the Envelope Mesh is created, you can use the **Warp Tool** to move anchors around, often easier than selecting anchors. I didn't feel this warranted a strikingly similar answer though.

Answer (score 3):

Photoshop's Filters > Distort Displace makes something resembling. Here's a screenshot of raw text:

[image]

Add a layer, draw something with black, white and grayshades:

[image]

Blur the result if you want smooth bumps. If you want generally smooth bumps, but also a folding, leave or repaint a sharp edge. Here are only smooth bumps:

[image]

Save the file as PSD. The black-grey-white pattern must be the top layer. Increase the canvas size to keep all forthcoming in the image, say 10%

Goto Filters > Distort > Displace. Set the displacement length (=px) amplitudes (white=+100%, Black =-100%) and edge treatment options and select the just saved displacement map file:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Note that all shifts are made to the same direction which depends on the selected amplitudes.

**If you want editable text**, do not have raster image text, but use a text layer or many at the same time selected layers and convert them to Smart Object. When you apply Displace to it, Photoshop generates a smart filter. You can edit it's content like any smart objects without quality nor effect losses.

Not asked: The displacement effect didn't in this case affect at all the understandability of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the software you have available, I can tell you if I were doing this, if I were OK with a fast, but destructive workflow, I'd probably use the **Liquify Persona** tools in Affinity Photo.

Like so:
[image]

Photoshop also has some decent Liquify tools which would enable the same level of control of warping and distortion.

Another approach in Photoshop would be to set up a white/black/grey map and load it into Photoshop as a displacement map - that could be a less destructive workflow. You select your type layer, go into **Filters>Distort>Displace** and this will tell you to either rasterise your type layer or make it a Smart Object (Smart Object better choice) and then ask you to point at a PSD for the displacement map.

I threw a super-quick diff clouds map that ended up looking like this:

[image]

Hope that helps.