# How to make bendy text in inkscape? (or adobe illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, text, distort

I'm trying to make tet bend in inkscape. Is there any efficient way to do this? I'm going for something like this (disregard the strings, it's from a hoodie):

[image]

I've tried adding the text to path and then moving the nodes manually. but there's got to be something better.

Comment: check this answer, for Illustrator https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84830/adobe-photoshop-illustrator-transform-type-to-give-it-wave-like-form-flow/84835#84835

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator has a **Warp Tool**. You could create outlines and use that....

[image]

This is just one method. There are more...

- [Adobe Photoshop/Illustrator: Transform type to give it wave-like form/flow](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84830/adobe-photoshop-illustrator-transform-type-to-give-it-wave-like-form-flow)
- [How to create curved texts like these?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/121477/how-to-create-curved-texts-like-these)
- [Distortion treatment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109163/distortion-treatment)

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Scott's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/157626/165916) there is also a 'Tweak' tool in Inkscape ([image: Tweak tool icon] or <kbd>W</kbd> by default) that lets you distort a path by dragging over it, if you set the mode to 'Push parts of paths ...' ([image: Push mode button]). However, I've found it to be somewhat finicky and a bit buggy.

An even quicker and less destructive method is using filters, though. There is even a built-in one in Inkscape with some variables you can play with. You can find it under 'Filters → Distort → Roughen...'. Note that filters do not change the underlying geometry and are only visual, so if you want to use it for laser-cutting for example, this won't work.

Anyways here are some settings I used to kinda recreate your reference:

[image: Roughen dialog]

And the result:

[image: Distorted text]

Comment: Appreciate it! Tysm!

Answer (score 1):

This is for Inkscape

If you want to actually distort the outlines rather than just use an effect, you can use the Tweak Tool <kbd>W</kbd> in Inkscape.

1. Convert the text to outlines using *Path > Object to Path*.
2. Engage the Tweak tool <kbd>W</kbd>, and in the tool options set it up like this, making sure to select the Push Paths button (highighted blue), set the fidelity to 100.

[image]

3. To help increase the warping effect, it's also worthwhile selecting all the nodes, and then you can use the Insert New Nodes button (highlighted red) to create more nodes for the Tweak tool to work on.

[image]

4. Finally use the tool on the letters to distort them.

[image]

Another method in Inkscape is to use the Lattice Deformation LPE. First convert text to paths as before, apply the LPE, and switch to the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>, then move the nodes of the lattice. Also, LPE effects can be baked in using *Path > Object to Path* if you need to covert to actual paths.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! So much to learn...